# How to remove checked items from a listbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, itemtemplate

I have been working on a checklist application, and I am using a `ListBox` to display the data.
I am using arrays to populate the `ListBox` based on what button the user presses. 
(I don't know if that's best practice but it works for now.)  Once the user has completed the steps, he can remove the items with this command:

```
private void SendSelected()
{
    while (lstToDo.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        lstToDo.Items.Remove(lstToDo.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

The problem is that today I have learned how to add `CheckBox`es to my `ItemTemplate` with the xaml below:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Padding="10">                            
                <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
            </CheckBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Now the remove button still works... however I would like to adjust it so that it removes the checked items instead of selected items.
In winforms, I used to do it like this:

```
while (lstToDo.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
{
    lstToDo.Items.Remove(lstToDo.CheckedItems[0]);
}
```

But in WPF, obviously this method doesn't work, and I am just not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind the checkbox to the IsSelected property of the ListBoxItem

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you Mustafa, that does work as expected. it is indeed a more elegant solution to what I have now. I am hesitant to use this solution though because it removes the padding I had from the actual box and the contents. Also, in the future I had planned on adding buttons to that stack panel.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper on your data, which will include view-specific data such as the IsChecked property. Bind the property to the CheckBox and then you'll be able to find all items that have been checked...

Simple Example:

```
public class CheckedItem<T> where T : class
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

So instead of a list of `MyItem` you create a list of `CheckedItem<MyItem>`

No just change the binding accordingly:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Padding="10" IsChecked={Binding IsChecked}>                            
                    <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                    </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                </CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And if you only want to remove the items that are Checked you can get them like this:

```
List<CheckedItem<MyItem>> MyItems; 
...
...

foreach (var Item in MyItems)
{
    if (!Item.IsChecked)
    {
         lstToDo.Items.Remove(Item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Solution. I want to mention that the most important realization the OP needs to have about this is that UI is not Data, therefore he should not expect to get the selection status from the UI itself, but from the Data items.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {   
   foreach(CheckedItem in lstToDo.SelectedItems)
  {
    (lsttoDo.ItemsSource as List).Remove(CheckedItem);
  }
    lsttoDo.Items.Refresh();
 }
```

In your `c#`.

Comment: Thank you Rachel, this is the solution I would like to use, however it gives me an error. "The name configSetListBox does not exist in the current context. Do I have to declare that somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing I tried but then I get this: The type or namespace name 'ConfigSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Do I need to add a reference somewhere? I can not find any info on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a `Model` for you Items with a Checked property, this way if you change the data in the UI the `MyList` will be updated and if you update items in `MyList` in code the UI will reflect the changes.

So if you remove all the checked items from `MyList` they will be removed from the `ListBox`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyItems.Add(new MyObject { Name = "Test1" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyObject { Name = "Test2" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyObject { Name = "Test3" });
        MyItems.Add(new MyObject { Name = "Test4" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyItems
    {
        get { return _myItems; }
        set { _myItems = value; }
    }

    public void RemoveItems()
    {
        // Remove any items fro MyList that "IsChecked"
    }
}

public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private bool _isChecked;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="199" Width="206" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Padding="10" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                            <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                            </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```