# How to get checked items from a listbox

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, checkbox, listbox

I am new to WPF and trying to add some checkbox items to a ListBox dynamically and then on click of the button I am trying to get the checked items from the listbox. But the problem is that there is no checked items being fetched. Following is the code of the listbox

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39.714,179,0,364.318" Name="ListBox1" Width="234" FontSize="16" SelectionMode="Multiple">

            <ListBox.BitmapEffect>
                <DropShadowBitmapEffect />
            </ListBox.BitmapEffect>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <CheckBox Content="Bleeding" Name="CheckBox1"></CheckBox>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <CheckBox Content="Bruising or Discoloration" Name="CheckBox2"></CheckBox>
            </ListBoxItem>
<DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and code on how am I fetching those checked items:

```
Dim l As New List(Of String)
For Each l1 As ListBoxItem In ListBox1.SelectedItems
    l.Add(l1.Content)
Next
```

I also referred to these questions: [How to get selected items from listbox has checkboxes in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525920/how-to-get-selected-items-from-listbox-has-checkboxes-in-wpf)
and 
[How to remove checked items from a listbox in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367898/remove-checked-items-from-a-listbox-in-wpf)

But didn't find any solution. Please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the checkbox is not selecting the item, this is why you don't get the expected behavior.

You can bind `IsChecked` property of check box to `IsSelected` property of list box item. To do this, the binding - on each check box - should be:

```
IsChecked="{Binging IsSelected, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSouce FindAncestor,
                                                  AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                    Mode="TwoWay"}"
```